# Remove duplicates from series of parenthesizes

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm trying to remove duplicates from a series of values enclosed by parenthesizes. Such as:

```
(QL)(M)(ST)(M)(PA)(AGE)(QL)
```

For some reason I'm getting erratic results from my Regex.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('(QL)(M)(QL)(M)(QL)', '(\(.*\))(.*?)\1', '\1') FROM DUAL;
```

results

```
(QL)(M)(QL)
```

It seems to only remove the first occurrence of each duplicate.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('(QL)(M)(QL)(M)(QL)(AGE)(ST)(PA)(ST)(ST)', 
    '(\(.*\))(.*?)\1', '\1') FROM DUAL;
```

results in

```
(QL)(M)(QL)(AGE)(ST)
```

The duplicate (QL) remains, and (PA) mysteriously disappeared.

Comment: Actually, you can't achieve that without a lookahead. It should be `(\(.*?\))(?=.*\1)` and replacement would be an empty string. However, Oracle regex does not seem to support lookarounds.

Comment: The reason you would need a lookahead is that it just looks, it won't advance the match position. Example `\((A)\).*?\1` would match `A B B A` and after replacement, it would be `A`, when it should be `A B`. The B's would be gone because it went past them and in reality, you just want to match the `A` then stop.